# Change dropdownlist selected value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have five dropdownlists on the form. I want that if user select something from one of dropdownlists, the other ones should be unselected. User can select something from just one dropdownlist.When he select something,selected value of other dropdownlists should be unselected. I'm using jquery

```
@foreach (var lay in Model.EventLayouts)
{
    <li>

    <select class="layoutSelect" layoutname="@lay.Name" layoutId="@lay.LayoutID" moderation="@lay.Moderation.ToString().ToLower()" selectedVal="0">

    <option value="0">@PageResources.Quantity</option>

    <option value="1">1</option>

    </select>

    </li>
}
```

Comment: What you have tried in jquery?

Comment: what is your default value for the dropdowns..? And have you bound change event for those dropdowns..?

Comment: @sudharsan something like dropdownlist change function but it didn't work

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy just a default text. it is option value ="0"

Comment: That why i am asking show me your code what you have tried.

Comment: just set the value to a non-existent value. like `$("#ddlId").val("");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that both dropdown has same `class="layoutSelect"` and unselect `value="0"`, try below jQuery :

```
$('.layoutSelect').change(function(){
   $('.layoutSelect').not(this).val('0');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DJw37/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
$(document).on('change', '.layoutSelect', function () {
if ($(this).find('option').is(":selected")) {
    $('.layoutSelect').not($(this)).val("");//val('0');
}
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gSALD/3/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to reset the other drop-downs but not the one which is changed, by adding same class on all drop-down  you can do like this:

```
$(".layoutSelect").change(function(){

$(".layoutSelect").not(this).val(0);

})
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/DJw37/)